# Spring application fails to run - Communications link failure -

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I trying to learn Spring  framework. I created a project using MySQL datase, Hibernate, Spring security, lombok. I'm using JDK 17, and apache-maven version 3.8.4. I started by creating the entities and adding the ManyToOne / OneToMany annotations.
When I run the project, I get this message:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.4.1\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=58649:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\BILELN\Desktop\BilelN\14 - Spring + Angular\gestiondestock\target\classes;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.7.3\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.7.3\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.22\spring-aop-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.7.3\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.22\spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.10.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.13\byte-buddy-1.12.13.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.6\jaxb-runtime-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.6\txw2-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.7.2\spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.7.2\spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.22\spring-orm-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.22\spring-context-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.22\spring-tx-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.22\spring-beans-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.22\spring-aspects-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.7.3\spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.7.3\spring-boot-starter-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.3\spring-boot-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.7.3\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.7.3\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.11\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.11\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.2\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.36\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.30\snakeyaml-1.30.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.7.3\spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.3\jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.3\jackson-annotations-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.3\jackson-core-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.3\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.7.3\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.65\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.65\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.65.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.65\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.22\spring-web-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.22\spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.22\spring-expression-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.30\mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.24\lombok-1.18.24.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.22\spring-core-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\BILELN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.22\spring-jcl-5.3.22.jar" com.neji.gestiondestock.ApiGestionDeStockApplication
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.3)

2022-09-15 11:57:44.678  INFO 15232 --- [           main] c.n.g.ApiGestionDeStockApplication       : Starting ApiGestionDeStockApplication using Java 17.0.4.1 on DELL-1QV4RG3 with PID 15232 (C:\Users\BILELN\Desktop\BilelN\14 - Spring + Angular\gestiondestock\target\classes started by BilelN in C:\Users\BILELN\Desktop\BilelN\14 - Spring + Angular\gestiondestock)
2022-09-15 11:57:44.678  INFO 15232 --- [           main] c.n.g.ApiGestionDeStockApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-09-15 11:57:44.996  INFO 15232 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-09-15 11:57:44.996  INFO 15232 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-09-15 11:57:45.260  INFO 15232 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2022-09-15 11:57:45.260  INFO 15232 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-09-15 11:57:45.260  INFO 15232 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-09-15 11:57:45.329  INFO 15232 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-09-15 11:57:45.329  INFO 15232 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 618 ms
2022-09-15 11:57:45.426  INFO 15232 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-09-15 11:57:45.444  INFO 15232 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
2022-09-15 11:57:45.513  INFO 15232 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-09-15 11:57:45.545  INFO 15232 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-09-15 11:57:46.595 ERROR 15232 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at 
...
...
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at com.neji.gestiondestock.ApiGestionDeStockApplication.main(ApiGestionDeStockApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    ... 52 common frames omitted

2022-09-15 11:57:46.595  WARN 15232 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at 
...
...
com.neji.gestiondestock.ApiGestionDeStockApplication.main(ApiGestionDeStockApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    ... 52 common frames omitted

2022-09-15 11:57:46.600  INFO 15232 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2022-09-15 11:57:46.695 ERROR 15232 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.neji.gestiondestock.model.LigneCommandeClient.idcommandeclient in com.neji.gestiondestock.model.CommandeClient.ligneCommandeClient
2022-09-15 11:57:46.695  WARN 15232 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.neji.gestiondestock.model.LigneCommandeClient.idcommandeclient in com.neji.gestiondestock.model.CommandeClient.ligneCommandeClient
2022-09-15 11:57:46.695  INFO 15232 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-09-15 11:57:46.701  INFO 15232 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-09-15 11:57:46.716 ERROR 15232 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.neji.gestiondestock.model.LigneCommandeClient.idcommandeclient in com.neji.gestiondestock.model.CommandeClient.ligneCommandeClient
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at com.neji.gestiondestock.ApiGestionDeStockApplication.main(ApiGestionDeStockApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.neji.gestiondestock.model.LigneCommandeClient.idcommandeclient in com.neji.gestiondestock.model.CommandeClient.ligneCommandeClient
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:875) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:826) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1653) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1629) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at 
...
...
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the properties file "application.yml":

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestiondestock?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&userSSL=false&useUnicode=true&JDBCCompliantTimezoneS
    username: root
    password:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
## Specify DBMS
  jpa:
    database: MYSQL
    show-sql: false
# Hibernate DDL Auto (create, create-drop, update)
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server:
  port: 8081
```

Here is the code where the message shows the error;
AbstractEntity.java

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class AbstractEntity implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name= "creationDate", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant creationDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name= "lastModifiedDate")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant lastModifiedDate;
}
```

CommandeClient.java:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "commandeclient")
public class CommandeClient extends AbstractEntity{
    @Column(name ="code")
    private String code;
    @Column(name ="datecommande")
    private Instant dateCommande;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idclient")
    private Client client;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idcommandeclient")
    private List<LigneCommandeClient> ligneCommandeClient;
}
```

LigneCommandeClient.java:

````
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "lignecommandeclient")
public class LigneCommandeClient extends AbstractEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idarticle")
    private Article article;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idcommandeclient")
    private CommandeClient commandeClient;
}
```

Here the main class "ApiGestionDeStockApplication.java":
```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiGestionDeStockApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGestionDeStockApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite exact.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.neji.gestiondestock.model.LigneCommandeClient.idcommandeclient in com.neji.gestiondestock.model.CommandeClient.ligneCommandeClient

`idcommandeclient` is not a field in the java class, but rather a column in the database table. `mappedby` always references a field in the java class. In this case it would be `commandeClient`. With the annotation it is `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "commandeClient")`

Comment: This does not resolve any

Comment: It definitely fixes `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property`. However if you have more issues, then those should come up one after another

Comment: It fixed the org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property but still other errors like ```at com.neji.gestiondestock.ApiGestionDeStockApplication.main(ApiGestionDeStockApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]```

Comment: That doesnt say anything. Do you mean you still get `com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure`?

Comment: Yes!
```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
.......
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure```

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai